# Storing Value as a Short

Tags: java, runtime-error, mips, offset, short

I am not sure why I keep getting this error but I was hoping someone could help me. I am trying to work  on a partial MIPS disassembler program in Java but when trying to store my I format offset (16 Bits) I get an error message(Stars where the error occurs):

```
private short offset;
                public void setOffset (String binary) {
                    **short s = Short.parseShort(this.binary.substring(15, 31),16);**

                    offset = s; 
                }
                public short getOffset(){
                    return offset;
                }
```

This is th error message I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1000000000001100"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Short.parseShort(Unknown Source)
at HexI.setOffset(HexI.java:65)
at MipsDisassembler.main(MipsDisassembler.java:31)
```

Essentially I would like to store it as a short and use bitwise operators to return a hex value

Comment: `public void setOffset (String binary)` but using `this.binary`

Answer (score 1):

```
short s = Short.parseShort(this.binary.substring(15, 31),16);
```

You are specifying radix 16 (hexadecimal) for the input when in actuality it should be `2` since the input is binary.

It should be

```
short s = Short.parseShort(this.binary.substring(15, 31),2);
                                                         ^
```

Comment: I just tried this but I am still getting an error message but this time that it is out of bounds.                                                                                      Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: Value out of range. Value:"1000000000001100" Radix:2